# Differentiate files based on there filename

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder of files I need to loop through.  Each file is to be processed differently based on their filename.  The part of the filename after the 2nd “_” is key to which process to follow.  Issue is, the names are similar and I cannot find a way to differentiate them.  They always come up as Process1.

Typical folder of files and code I have tried:

```
NV_DB62_mainx_.dxf
NV_DB62_mainxsplashroad.dxf
NV_DB62_mainxplashroadONLY.dxf
NV_DB62_mainsplash.dxf
NV_DB63_mainx_dxf
NV_DB63_mainxsplashroad.dxf
NV_DB63_mainxplashroadONLY.dxf
NV_DB63_mainsplash.dxf
```

```vb
Set App = CreateObject("Illustrator.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder("S:\NV\Section_13\Road DXFs")

Dim FileRef
For Each FileRef In SourceFolder.Files
   If Instr(FileRef,"mainx") > 0 then
       Call Process1(FileRef)
   ElseIf Instr(FileRef,"mainxsplashroad") > 0 then
       Call Process2(FileRef)
   ElseIf Instr(FileRef,"mainxsplashroadONLY") > 0 then
       Call Process3(FileRef)
   ElseIf Instr(FileRef,"mainsplash") > 0 then
       Call Process4(FileRef)
   Else
       Msgbox "File is not being found or some issue with script."
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Change the order you do the test. Longest first, shortest last.

Comment: The debugger would show you why your code isn't working, and a little common sense would tell you why. If you're checking for `mainx` first, and it's in every single filename, clearly it will always pass that test. Change the order to test for the longest name first, then the next longest, then the third longest, and so on until the shortest name becomes the final test.

Comment: Also specify `if LCase(Mid(fileref.name, 8)=LCase("mainx_dxf")`
`

Comment: @KenWhite In his defense, VBScript doesn't come with a debugger, and the MS Script Debugger has been deprecated and removed from downloads. Rob van der Woude has a pretty helpful list of [debugging techniques for VBScript](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_debugging.php), though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers agreed but MS Script Debugger isn't the only option, Visual Studio will debug VBScript, either attach to the process or force it using `/x` command line switch.

Comment: I think you better off use `Select Case Split(FileRef,"_mainx")(1)...` under `If Instr(FileRef,"_mainx") > 0 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

As Noodles pointed out in the comments, this is an algorithm problem.

You'll need to search for the entries from most- to least-specific.  That is, each If/ElseIf test shouldn't match any of the conditions below it (right now, your `"mainx"` first test matches the two immediately below it).